# mongodb - How to do a substring on $lookup foreignField

Tags: mongodb

```
db.tempCollection.aggregate(    
  {
    $lookup: { 
      "from" : "SensorInfo", 
      "localField" : "pid", 
      "foreignField" :{ $substr: [ "$pid", 0, 8 ] }, //Substring
      "as" : "sind_docs"
    }
  });
```

When I try with the above syntax, seeing a $ cannot be in field error message. Similiar message with pid instead of $pid

How to do substr in this situation?

Comment: You can't. The error message is explicit about this. The best you can do is create the `$lookup` pipeline dynamically i.e. get the actual `pid` substring value and use that when creating the pipeline before running it.

Comment: Thanks @chridam. I was able to use $project and get the substr of pid. Now I'd like to use this result in another lookup's foreign field. Is that even possible with chained $lookup operators? My query runs fine when I use pid, but no returns no data

Answer (score 1):

From Mongo 3.6

```
db.tempCollection.aggregate(    
{
  $lookup: { 
    "from" : "SensorInfo",
    "let": { localPid: "$pid" },
    "pipeline": [
      { $match:
        { $expr:
          {
            $eq: [ "$$localPid",  { $substr: [ "$foreignPid", 0, 7 ] } ]
          }
        }
      },
    ],
    "as" : "sind_docs"
  }
});
```